# Android отправка запроса на сервер каждую минуту даже если приложение закрыто

Tags: android, android-service

Суть такая: есть внутренне приложение фирмы для мониторинга координат при перемещении. 
Задача отправлять запрос с устройства на сервер с новыми данными.
Я пытался сделать и сервисом, и потоками, и другие примеры с интернета брал, но если приложение умирает, то и запросы передаваться перестают.

Задача что бы оно выполнялось по таймеру в не зависимости от активности приложения.
Если у кого-то есть полезная для меня ссылка, или пример такого сервиса буду безмерно признателен!

Comment: для сервиса нужно указать чтобы он был неубиваемый, и он будет работать даже в случае закрытия приложения.

Comment: startForegroundService

Comment: WorkManager с репитом каждую минуту, либо обычный Service, но с уведомлениями ибо дольше 10 секунд и система начиная с Android 7+ убьет службу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания сервиса, который не будет убит системой необходимо, чтобы этот сервис постоянно поддерживал уведомление.

Пример такого сервиса:

```
class MyForegraundService : Service(){
    companion object {
        const val channelId = "--your channel id--"
        const val notifyId = 395 // some number
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("Your service started")
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

        override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        sendStartNotification()
        doWhatYouNeed()// your code
    }
}
```

Где sendStartNotification:

```
private fun sendStartNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createChannel()
    val notification = buildNotification()
    this.startForeground(notifyId, notification)
}

private fun buildNotification(): Notification {
    val builder = notificationBuilder

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_6)
            .setContentTitle(this.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.resources.getString("describe process"))
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setProgress(100, 0, true)
            .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
    return builder.build()
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createChannel() {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val name = getString("notification_channel_name")// for user
    val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    channel.description = getString("notification_channel_description") //for user
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Пример где можно почитать: https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/

Гуглится по запросу ForegroundService.

Если простыми словами, то такой сервис будет жить до тех пор, пока висит уведомление, а уведомление создается несмахиваемым. Очевидно, перезагрузка устройства сервис убьет. Так же бывает, что система убивает даже такой сервис, но это случается нечасто (на практике пока ни разу встретилось), а пользователь имеет возможность увидеть, что сервис убит. При остановке сервиса нужно убрать/заменить уведомление.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне прояснили принцип как это работает!